# How to block Alexa and Similar Web to access website

Tags: search, seo, analytics, alexa-skills-kit

I need to perevent Alexa and Similar web from accessing my website completely.
I understand that it's can be done with robots.txt, but as far as i know it's not enough and they are collection data with simple extensions or something similar.

Any ideas or solutions?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yaniv, have you found a solution fo this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to block theire bots with robots.txt

- Alexa bot: ia_archiver

This is how you block it:

```
User-agent: ia_archiver
Disallow: /
```

You need to find names of all the bots you want to block. It is pretty easy, just use Google search